# Upgrade spring data mongo db version

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

Can i upgrade spring data mongo version to 2.2 without upgrading the spring framework version. Currently i am using spring framework version 3.2. I need to upgrade spring data mongo db version to support mongo db 4.2 TLS support.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The 2.x generation of Spring Data requires Spring 5 at least. Spring Framework 3.2 is severely out of date and not maintained anymore. Spring 4 was released over 6 years ago. I can only strongly recommend to upgrade to a currently maintained version to make sure you benefit from security fixes that the 3.x generation has already not seen anymore for years.

Comment: Can we spring data mongodb version 1.9.5 to connect mongo db 4.2 over TLS and with spring 3.2.

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB 1.9 is part of the Hopper release train which also has been out of maintenance for 2.5 years. It requires Spring 4.2. Again, I can only recommend to upgrade to more recent versions of both Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Framework.